# algorithm complexity question of f>>g & f>g

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

`f>g` means that `f>=g` *(`f` dominates `g`)* and `g` does not dominate `f`.

`f>>g` means that `cf>g` *(eventually)* for any `c>0`

What's the difference?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Perhaps try at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is not about programming

Comment: cstheory is for **research** level computer science questions. Not for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example:

```
f = 2n
g = n
```

You can see that `f > g` but `f not >> g` because you can choose `c == 0.1` and then `cf will never be > g`.

However:

```
f = n^2
g = 2n
```

You can see that at first `g>f` but eventually `f>g` for large enough `n` and no matter how small you make `c`, eventually `cf` will become larger than `g`. Therefore `f>>g`.

Comment: thanks, but f>g is not f>=g, which also means g not > f. what i want to know is that why define > and >>, for these seems the same but i don't know the difference.

Comment: @elfandi Sorry, could you clarify you statement about "f>g is not f>=g" and how it relates to your question?

Comment: your answer is about how f>=g differs from f>>g, and my question is that f>g differs from f>>g. f>g means f>=g and g not >=f.  f>>g -> f>g, f>g not necessarily implies f>>g. i want to know the counter-example.

Answer (score -1):

`>` can  be read greater than   where
`>>` can be read as much greater than

Difference is in approximations for instance

if  `a>>b` then  `a+b` is approximetly same as  `a` , where you can not say if only  `a>b` holds.

Comment: In the case described in his question, I believe it meant something different. See my answer.

Comment: What I wrote is one of uses that you described. My answer is just one of many possibilities where this distinction come handy.

Comment: Overloaded operators in Mathematics and Computer science are complicated enough, without anyone giving explicitely the wrong meaning to an operator in a certain context.